# foreach in foreach in turn to do 2nd foreach once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need du foreach in foreach in turn rotation, to do once 2nd foreach and after do first foreach and do 2nd foreach twice

```
foreach (var name in xml.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>()
    .Select(x => x.Name).Distinct())
    {

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        string str = name.ToString();


        foreach (var name1 in xml.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>()
            .Select(x => x.Value).Distinct())
            {
                column = new WebGridColumn();
                column.ColumnName = str;
                StringWriter sw1 = new StringWriter();
                XmlTextWriter tx1 = new XmlTextWriter(sw1);
                string str1 = name1.ToString();

                column.Format = (item) => str1;

                listelem.Add(column);
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: still not clear what you want to do?

Comment: every time when i'm break "name1" is start from firts I need to start from 2nd, after start from 3rd .... 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a bool flag like this

```
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (var name in xml.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>()
                                           .Select(x => x.Name).Distinct())
        {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
            string str = name.ToString();
            int localCounter = -1;
            {
            foreach (var name1 in xml.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>()
                 .Select(x => x.Value).Distinct())
            {
                localCounter++;
                if(localCounter < counter)
                   {

                     continue;
                    }
               counter++;
                column = new WebGridColumn();
                column.ColumnName = str;
                StringWriter sw1 = new StringWriter();
                XmlTextWriter tx1 = new XmlTextWriter(sw1);
                string str1 = name1.ToString();

                column.Format = (item) => str1;

                listelem.Add(column);
                break;
            }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Am impressed that you understand what OP was asking

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks a lot :) I tried to guess .....

Comment: it's don't work again only firs element in 2rd foreach

Comment: @user3359460 I have changed my logic can verify once . It is very inefficient. We can optimize in case you think logic is Ok

Comment: and please don't be streng with me I'm little in english

Comment: Thank you all very much it work's